# Simple histogram algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, histogram

Im creating a histogram algorithm. Im following the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515959/1246159).

I want to simply count the number of times each value has occurred.

However I cant quite get the algorithm right. My code is:

```
var values = [2, 4, 6, 3, 3];

var val_max = 6;
var val_min = 2;

var num_bins = parseInt(val_max - val_min + 1);
console.log('num_bins is ', num_bins);

var bin_width = (val_max-val_min)/num_bins;
console.log('bin_width is ', bin_width);

var to_plot = [];

for (var i = 0; i < num_bins; i++) {
  to_plot.push(0);
}

for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {

    var bin_idx = parseInt((values[x] - val_min) / bin_width); 

    to_plot[bin_idx] = to_plot[bin_idx] + 1; 
}

console.log('to_plot is ', to_plot);
```

If you look at the console logs, you'll see:

```
to_plot is  [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, NaN]
```

I want that last index to be "1". But the problem is for values close the the maximum value, `bin_idx` is out of range. How can I tweak this so that I would get the following results?

```
to_plot is  [1, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ka74jmg/1/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binning an array in javascript for a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445495/binning-an-array-in-javascript-for-a-histogram)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```js
const data = [2, 4, 6, 3, 3];

print(histogram(data, 1)); // [1, 2, 1, 0, 1]
print(histogram(data, 2)); // [3, 1, 1]
print(histogram(data, 3)); // [4, 1]
print(histogram(data, 4)); // [4, 1]
print(histogram(data, 5)); // [5]

function histogram(data, size) {
    let min = Infinity;
    let max = -Infinity;

    for (const item of data) {
        if (item < min) min = item;
        else if (item > max) max = item;
    }

    const bins = Math.ceil((max - min + 1) / size);

    const histogram = new Array(bins).fill(0);

    for (const item of data) {
        histogram[Math.floor((item - min) / size)]++;
    }

    return histogram;
}

function print(x) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
}
```

This works for non-integer values too.

Comment: Fantastic solution. This works very well. It looks like i'll have to use a logarithmic scale as some values are far too large. So this works very well as ill be working with floats. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your `bin_width` is wrong.  Try this calculation instead:

```
var bin_width = (val_max - val_min) / (num_bins - 1);
```

That makes the `bin_width == 1` which lets the rest of your code work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of bins is equal to the number of integers between `val_min` and `val_max`, the `bin_width` is 1, not 0.8 as currently being calculated.  You're basically counting integers here.  Use this loop to generate the histogram:

```
for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    to_plot[values[x] - val_min] ++;
}
```

Comment: Yes true, ill go with this solution

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in histogram outputs rather than on the implementation, the [d3-array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) library provides a `bin()` method that is useful to build histograms.

The following is a thin wrapper on top of `bin()`, in Typescript, that adds some features and provides an output similar to [Python's numpy.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

```js
/**
 * Computes histogram of an array of numbers.
 *
 * @remarks
 * Requires library d3-array.
 *
 * @param arr - The input array of numbers.
 * @param nBins - Optional number of bins desired. Auto if not passed.
 * @param domain - Optional minimum and maximum bin edge values.
 * @param clamp - Whether to clamp values in arr to the domain.
 *    Only relevant if domain is passed. If clamp is false (default),
 *    data outside the domain will be lost. If clamp is true, the data will
 *    be kept in the first or last bin.
 * @returns An object with keys hist, containing the count of values in
 *    each bin, and binEdges, containing the edges of each bin.
 */
export const computeHistogram = (
  arr: number[],
  nBins?: number,
  domain?: [number, number],
  clamp: boolean = false
) => {
  if (domain && clamp) {
    const [domainMin, domainMax] = domain;
    arr.forEach((val, i, arr) => {
      arr[i] = Math.min(Math.max(val, domainMin), domainMax);
    });
  }
  let bins = d3Array.bin();
  if (domain) bins = bins.domain(domain);
  if (nBins) bins = bins.thresholds(nBins);
  const d3Hist = bins(arr);
  const hist: number[] = d3Hist.map((item) => item.length);
  const binEdges = d3Hist.map((item) => item.x0);
  if (d3Hist.length) binEdges.push(d3Hist.at(-1)!.x1);

  return { hist, binEdges };
};
```