# Binning Array in javascript for Histogram

Tags: arrays, d3.js, histogram

I am referring to the earlier question posted. Link (([Binning an array in javascript for a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445495/binning-an-array-in-javascript-for-a-histogram) ) and was successful to some extent.

I am getting array(through api) which has nos like [null,null,6,45,63.....].

I would like to make bins using d3 and once the bins are available...I can plot in chart.

```
var arr = [
 "0.847402", "0.847747", "0.790411", "0.835979", "0.838546".....]

var bins = [];
var binCount = 0;
var interval = .05;
var numOfBuckets = 1;

//Setup Bins
for(var i = 0; i < numOfBuckets; i += interval){
  bins.push({
    binNum: binCount,
    minNum: i,
    maxNum: i + interval,
    count: 0
  })
  binCount++;
}

//Loop through data and add to bin's count
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var item = arr[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < bins.length; j++){
    var bin = bins[j];
    if(item > bin.minNum && item <= bin.maxNum){
      bin.count++;
    }
  }  
}


However expected output is :
[[object Object] {
  binNum: 0,
  count: 0,
  maxNum: 0.05,
  minNum: 0
}, [object Object] {
  binNum: 1,
  count: 0,
  maxNum: 0.1,
  minNum: 0.05
}, [object Object] {
  binNum: 2,
  count: 0,
  maxNum: 0.15000000000000002,
  minNum: 0.1
}, [object Object] {
  binNum: 3,
  count: 0,
  maxNum: 0.2,
  minNum: 0.15000000000000002
}, [object Object] {
  binNum: 4,
  count: 0,
  maxNum: 0.25,
  minNum: 0.2 ……………………………..]

However, my output so far is  only displaying one result:

[object Object] {
  binNum: 1,
  count: 0,
  maxNum: 0.1,
  minNum: 0.05
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but you are only creating one bin: `numOfBuckets = 1;`

Comment: Yes..thats the output I am getting....I should get more...my data is from 0 to 300...and making bins of 20 each...still this output...

Comment: But why do you expect more bins when your for statement only iterates once and creates only one bin in your bins array here: `for(var i = 0; i < numOfBuckets; i += interval){ bins.push(...` where `numOfBuckets = 1`. What is  your output if you change `numOfBuckets` to 10 or 100?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for guiding me !!! Appreciate your response. So I followed your suggestion ….it worked.  :) Additionally , I add a max value to take from my json array...max value and placed in numofBuckets: maxValue….Thanks once again!!!!