# Javascript Filtering Array Start with 0 instead of Empty

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a distribution table, using this code. The code works except when one of distributions has 0 values that fit in it's range, it returns nothing instead of 0. For exp: It should be {"0<0.25",1, "0.26<.50",5,  "0.51<.75",0,  "0.76<1",2} instead it appears {"0<0.25",1, "0.26<.50",5, "0.76<1",2}. I was thinking to create an initial array with all zeros instead of empty array but having trouble doing that. Thanks for help.

```
        for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                Array.prototype.zip = function (other, reduce, thisArg) {
                var i, result = [], args,
                    isfunc = typeof reduce == "function",
                    l = Math.max(this.length, other.length);

                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    args = [this[i], other[i]];
                    result.push(isfunc ? reduce.apply(thisArg, args) : args);
                }
                return result;
            }

            const debt_outstanding = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.debt-outstanding-data'))
            const total_assets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.total-assets-data'))

            const A = total_assets.map((element) => element.innerText)
            const B = debt_outstanding.map((element) => element.innerText)
            const C = A.zip(B, function (l, r) {
                return (l / (l - r)) - 1;
            });

            let avg_leverage_ratios_value_inner_text = document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="avg-leverage-ratio"]`)[i]
            let problemTypeChoice = 0;




            var result = C.reduce(function (agg, item) {
                var key = "other";
                if (item < .25) key = "0<0.25";
                if (item > .26 && item < .50) key = "0.26<.50";
                if (item > .51 && item < .75) key = "0.51<.75";
                if (item > .76 && item < 1) key = "0.76<1";
                if (item > 1.01 && item < 1.5) key = "1.01<1.5";
                if (item > 1.51 && item < 2.5) key = "1.51<2.5";
                if (2.51 < item) key = "2.5>";
                agg[key] = (agg[key] || 0) + 1
                return agg;
            }, {})

            var values = Object.values(result);
            // bar chart data
            var barData = {
                labels: ["0 - 0.25", "0.26 - 0.50", "0.50 - 0.75", "0.75 - 1", "1.00 - 1.50", "1.50 - 2.50", "2.50 -"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(179,25,30,0.76)",
                        strokeColor: "#C03838",
                        data: values
                    },

                ]
            }
            // get bar chart canvas
            var leverage_chart = document.getElementById("leverage-chart").getContext("2d");

            // draw bar chart
            new Chart(leverage_chart).Bar(barData);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked out this post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445495/binning-an-array-in-javascript-for-a-histogram. The second answer has a working function that would just take the initial bins min/max values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not initialize the reduce `agg` paramater with the keys and zeroes instead of `{}` ?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  Array.prototype.zip = function(other, reduce, thisArg) {
    var i, result = [],
      args,
      isfunc = typeof reduce == "function",
      l = Math.max(this.length, other.length);

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      args = [this[i], other[i]];
      result.push(isfunc ? reduce.apply(thisArg, args) : args);
    }
    return result;
  }

  const debt_outstanding = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.debt-outstanding-data'))
  const total_assets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.total-assets-data'))

  const A = total_assets.map((element) => element.innerText)
  const B = debt_outstanding.map((element) => element.innerText)
  const C = A.zip(B, function(l, r) {
    return (l / (l - r)) - 1;
  });

  let avg_leverage_ratios_value_inner_text = document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="avg-leverage-ratio"]`)[i]
  let problemTypeChoice = 0;




  var result = C.reduce(function(agg, item) {
    var key = "other";
    if (item < .25) key = "0<0.25";
    if (item > .26 && item < .50) key = "0.26<.50";
    if (item > .51 && item < .75) key = "0.51<.75";
    if (item > .76 && item < 1) key = "0.76<1";
    if (item > 1.01 && item < 1.5) key = "1.01<1.5";
    if (item > 1.51 && item < 2.5) key = "1.51<2.5";
    if (2.51 < item) key = "2.5>";
    agg[key] = (agg[key] || 0) + 1
    return agg;
  }, {
    "other": 0,
    "0<0.25": 0,
    "0.26<.50": 0,
    "0.51<.75": 0,
    "0.76<1": 0,
    "1.01<1.5": 0,
    "1.51<2.5": 0,
    "2.5>": 0
  })

  var values = Object.values(result);
  // bar chart data
  var barData = {
    labels: ["0 - 0.25", "0.26 - 0.50", "0.50 - 0.75", "0.75 - 1", "1.00 - 1.50", "1.50 - 2.50", "2.50 -"],
    datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(179,25,30,0.76)",
        strokeColor: "#C03838",
        data: values
      },

    ]
  }
  console.log(barData);
}
```